# Recording failed orders?

Tags: add-on, expresso-store, ecommerce

Store 1.6.1 and Latest EE

Using PayPal Express. When a customer is transfered to PayPal but then decides to back out of the purchase, either by clicking the return to vendors website link or simply going else where - the failed order details are not recorded in Store (or am I wrong?). Be nice if they were, as the store owner could then follow up and perhaps make a sale.

Thanks
Lee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to see any failed orders by going to Orders under the Store dropdown menu and then clicking the Filter By Order Status dropdown and selecting Incomplete.